# Lebesgue differentiation theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E\subset[0,1]$ be a set whose Lebesgue measure is zero.

> I have to show:

1. for each $n\in\mathbb N$ there exists an open set $V_n$ such that $E\subset V_n$ and $m(V_n)<1/2^n$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.
2. For each $n\in\mathbb N$, let $\chi_{n}$ be the characteristic function of the set $V_n$ from part (a) above. Let
   $$
   g=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_{n}.
   $$
   Prove that $g\in L^1(\mathbb R)$

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Part 1 is almost immediate from the definition. What is the definition of the Lebesgue measure of a set?

Comment: Part 2 uses the monotone convergence theorem and not much else.

Comment: Thank you so much your help @UmbertoP. . For part a I assume E is cantor set ,But I don't get it how to show it. Can you please give me little bit more hints?

Comment: @UmbertoP.  did you mean this defination:>Lebesgue outer measure: For a subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$, we have that $m^*(E)=\inf\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ell(I_n):E\subset \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n\}$ and Lebesgue inner measure: For a subset $E$ of a bounded interval $[a,b]$, we have that $m_*(E)=b-a-m^*([a,b]\setminus E)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lebesgue (outer) measure of a set $E \subset \mathbf R$ is defined as $$m^*(E) = \inf \sum_k \ell(I_k)$$ where the infimum is taken over all countable families of open intervals $\{I_k\}$ whose union contains $E$.  If $m^*(E) < \infty$ then (by the definition of the infimum) for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a family $\{I_k\}$ of open intervals whose union contains $E$ and that satisfies $$\sum_k \ell(I_k) < m^*(E) + \epsilon.$$ In particular if $m^*(E) = 0$ then there is such a collection satisfying $$\sum_k \ell(I_k) < \epsilon.$$ If you let $V = \cup_k I_k$ then $V$ is open, $E \subset V$, and
$$m^*(V) = m^*(\cup_k I_k) \le \sum_k m^*(I_k) = \sum_k \ell(I_k) < \epsilon.$$

As far as part 2 is concerned, the monotone convergence theorem (or perhaps more accurately Beppo Levi's theorem) gives you
$$\int g = \int \sum_n \chi_n = \sum_n \int \chi_n = \sum_n m(V_n) < \sum_n 2^{-n} = 1.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.